# running all python files on MAC with anaconda environment

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, automator, finder

I'd like to start all files with the extension "py" from the finder in MAC using anaconda environment, just with clicking on the file.
Using the terminal with "python myfile.py" runs fine, but how can I start this directly with clicking on the file "myfile.py"  within the finder.

Comment: You could set the default 'open with' to be your IDE, and run the file from there, but that is probably not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with *Automator*:

1. Start up Automator
2. Choose application
3. In the Actions bar, select Library, and search for Shell
4. Drag "Run Shell Script" to the right pane.
5. Change pass input to "as arguments"
6. Change the script to

   for f in "$@" do python "$f" done
7. Save it (possibly in the application folder, but can be anywhere) as Python.app
8. Now if you want .py files to always launch with python:

   Select a .py file
   File -> Get Info
   In the Open with selection, choose Other, and select the Python.app you created.
   Click Change All

---

You may also have to set the shebang for it to pick your virtualenv:

If you want to run it from the terminal without using the `python` command, you can 
set the shebang to your anaconda environment as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python <- ADD Your Anaconda environment path here
```

then in terminal do this:

```
chmod +x ./myfile.py
```

And then you can just execute it as `./myfile.py` if it is executable.

Comment: and how can I do so that the outputs going  to a new terminal widow?

Comment: Go to a new terminal window meaning? Also, can you accept the answer.

Comment: Id like to use the print statement in Python and would like to see this output in a new terminal window

Comment: You can redirect the output to a log file. You can also print it out to the current terminal window but not a new terminal window.